# Apache proxy error to Bokeh server

Tags: fedora, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

my goal is to deploy a Bokeh application on an Apache server running under Fedora 25. After starting the bokeh server...

`2017-05-10 18:17:27,759 Starting Bokeh server on port 5100 with applications at paths ['/clsMaster']`

and after starting the apache server I get

```
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /clsMaster.
Reason: DNS lookup failure for: 127.0.0.1:5100clsmaster
```

when I put in the IP of the server in a browser: `http://10.10.10.10:80/clsMaster/`

So I checked my `/etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd_bokeh.conf` but I to spot the error

```
   ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
   Listen 80
   Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
   User apache
   Group apache
   ServerName localhost

 <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dashboard/
    ServerAdmin name@admin.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/dashboard/logs/bokeh-error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/dashboard/logs/bokeh-access_log common

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5100/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5100/

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5100/clsMaster/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5100/clsMaster/

    <Directory />
            Require all granted
            Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

    Alias /static /var/www/dashboard/static
    <Directory /var/www/dashboard/static>
            Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

My folder structure for the dashboard is the following

```
/var/www/dashboard/
    |
    +---data
    |     +---mydata.csv
    |
    +---clsMaster.py
    |
    +---static
    |      +----some.html
```

Strangely, there are no logs produced on the path that I specified `var/www/dashboard/logs/bokeh-error_log`. I have no access to `/var/log/httpd/`.

What I also don't understand is that when I leave out the `clsMaster` in the URL, so `http://10.10.10.10:80` I get `Service unavailable...` instead of the proxy error from above.